# What are the pitfalls of granting a weapon with at-will Benign Transposition?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, weapons

I am running a game of 3.5 D&D which includes a melee fighter who refuses to do anything other than melee (will not pick up a bow, etc.). That’s fine, and he’s doing great with the non-combat problem solving and such, but the party is reaching tenth level where “hits things with sword” starts to have trouble contributing to fights.

I plan to mitigate this in part by giving the character an overpowered sword that’s mostly really good at stabbing demons. This is appropriate to the campaign, and should make “apply fighter to problem” a more viable solution for a few more levels.

I am also looking at adding at-will Benign Transposition to the sword. Aside from confusion with how Scouts work, are there any pitfalls or problems with access to this effect?

Specifically, the planned sword is a +3 Starmetal Holy Speed Evil-Outsider Bane longsword. It provides a +4 Holy strength bonus and a Protection from Evil effect to the wielder, and allows him to use Benign Transposition (as the spell) at will. I am fairly confident with the other effects though (permanent Protection is cheesy, weird bonus types mess with stacking rules, etc), and am primarily interested in Benign Transposition.

Comment: Will the demon-killing sword be an intelligent magic item therefore capable of using its own actions to activate the *benign transposition* effect? (Presumably using the effect not on itself but on its wielder therefore *including* itself!) Or must the sword's wielder use his actions to activate the sword's *benign transposition* effect?

Comment: @HeyICanChan good point. The action economy is safe; specifics added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### That seems fine.

Compare your weapon to having a Wand Chamber

> A wand chamber is a thin, cylindrical slot on the handle of a weapon or the edge of a shield that can hold a single wand. When a wand is loaded in the chamber, it is considered ready and can be activated without having to drop the weapon or shield. Changing the wand in the chamber is a full-round action. 
>   Price: +100 gp (Dungeonscape p.34)

It still takes his standard action to use the effect, a level 1 wand is cheap (750 gp.) and it's effectively like having  Benign Transposition at will.

Because Benign Transposition already has a generous range (Medium (100 ft. + 10 ft./level)) caster level 1 should be fine, though one might quibble if it's higher.